# SDK Manager - Won't install new packages (install button remains "unclickable")

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, package

I have a very annoying problem, when I try to open an imported project with my version of Eclipse, it tells me that I can't do it unless I download the version 21 of something.
Then it opens my SDK Manager and when I want to install the new packages to update my version, it's just impossible even after having accepted the terms and conditions.

Here is a picture :
[image]

Any help is welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  First Clear your cache with `Android SDK Manager--> Tools--> Option-->click on Clear cache` after Refreshing the List by 
`Android SDK Manager --> Packages --> Reload`

Hope it will Help

Comment: I have the similar problem. I tried both options above and rebooted the my windows machine also. But it is still same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set the proxy settings in **Tools->Options**.

Inside Internet explorer, Press Alt+t -> Select Internet Options -> **connections** tab -> Click **Lan settings**. You can see Proxy settings there.