# Can't install Android SDK packages on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, osx-lion

I'm trying to install the current version of the Android SDK onto a Mac running OSX 10.7.5.

After downloading and unzipping the file to my home directory (where I have full write permissions), I opened the `SDK > Tools` folder and ran the *"android"* application.  This opens  the Android SDK Manager window.  If I check the boxes next to the *"Tools"* folder and next to each Android API version from 3.0 up to 4.1.2 and then click the *"Install 35 packages..."* button, I'm taken to the *"Choose Packages to Install"* window.

But the "Install" button in this window is disabled and all I see in the pane on the left are packages that I don't want to install (e.g. `Googletv License` and `Android SDK License`) and they all have question marks next to them.  I don't see a list of the packages (with green checkmarks) that I do want installed.

What am I doing wrong?  I tried reloading the packages as mentioned in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999058/sdk-manager-wont-install-new-packages-install-button-remains-unclickable) but there isn't an option under Tools to clear the cache.

Comment: did you checked the accept checkbox?

Comment: Indeed, on the right side is a license text area. Below that, there should be a "accept" or "accept all" checkbox/radiobutton. You need to activate it to get the install button active. In some rare cases this will still not work, than just close and retry the same thing.

Comment: The Accept and Reject radio buttons are both disabled. The Accept License button isn't disabled but when I click it, it doesn't stay "clicked" and the Install button remains disabled.

Comment: Also, I just tried it on another computer, a MacBook Air which is also running 10.7.5, and I get the same behavior there.

Comment: I tried rebooting just in case I was short on memory but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue. Select packages->Reload to refresh the cache. Then deselected All the items and manually just selected the android tools. Pressed install for that one package. The license window then pops up and you can accept the license and install the updated tools. Once it is done, close down and re-open the Android SDK Manager. Once it is re-launched it will select all the packages again that need updating, but this time, when you select "install X packages..." and it takes you to the license screen, you will be able to accept all the licenses and then the "install" button will be enabled.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

on "choose package to install", select the package from the left panel (the description should show up on your right) and then the radio button for "Accept License" will work and the Install button should be ok aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem with OSX 10.10 and Android Studio 1.2.2.  I was able to resolve by going to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... Then clicking the invalidate and restart button.  Not sure if a restart or just clearing the caches independently would have worked.

I was able to install packages after that.

Answer (score -1):

The above didn't work for me. I am on OSX Sierra on a MacBook Pro. I couldn't click the items in the window on the left. The way around it for me was simply using the cursor keys! That came to me after an hour of rebooting, re-downloading, re-loading packages. (First day using a Mac!)

But... It worked for me, hope it helps someone else!